# What is the scene of Kokonotsu looking off at the horizon a reference to?

Tags: dagashi-kashi

In episode 8, after Tou purchases a kendama it skips to a dramatized scene portraying his manliness:

[image: Picture from episode 8]

I'm sure this is a reference to some older anime. What is this scene a reference to?

Comment: It makes me think of Albator.